# Solutions of a matrix - Elementary question

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A simple question, are multiples of `r = [1 0]T` solutions to the matrix below.

Shouldn't it be `r = [0 1]T`?

`T = transpose`.

[image]

Comment: The original problem was probably to find $(r_1,r_2)^T$ and row reduction has created the form you have with $r_1$ and $r_2$ interchanged.

Comment: @Paul Yes, that explained everything. Thanks.